# JS: select the same attribute in every object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have an array of objects, for example:

```
var cars = [{name:"Geronimo", color:"red"},{name:"Ronaldo",color:"green"}]
```

Is there a simple way Im not seeing to select all the "color" attributes? So that I would get:
*"red", "green"*

So say something like **(INVENTED**):
`console.log(cars[selectingallobjects].name)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you'll have to iterate over each array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a ready way of doing that, you need to iterate to get the values.

You can use `.map()`, an Array method that creates a new array based on the values returned from the function.

It can be done in a single line.

See below:

```js
var cars = [{name:"Geronimo", color:"red"},{name:"Ronaldo",color:"green"}]

let result = cars.map(car => car.color)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for-loop and take only color property

```js
var cars = [{name:"Geronimo", color:"red"},{name:"Ronaldo",color:"green"}]
var carNames = []
for(car of cars){
  carNames.push(car['color'])
}
console.log(carNames)// [ "red", "green" ]
```

use `map` which is method creates a new array:

```js
var carNames = cars.map(car=>car.color)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` to do the following, it loops for every object in the array.

```js
var cars = [{name:"Geronimo", color:"red"},{name:"Ronaldo",color:"green"}]

cars.map((eachObject)=>{
  console.log(eachObject.color);
});
```

Comment: Inside map `return eachObject.color` not  `console log`it

Comment: Ik, just to help him understand

Comment: He wants an array of only colors. He doesn't ask for display them!

Comment: and loop for it again to get values? why not use them directly :/

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Thats not too complex, good!

Comment: @weaksou, you're using `.map()` as though it is `.forEach()` ....

Comment: map returns an array by default, just assign it to a variable.